# Java how to bottom align button and filter label to right

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, jlabel

Hi I am trying to make a GUI using Javax to look something like this.
[image]

But currently it looks like this
[image]

This is my code

```
class Intro extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton ok;
    JLabel background;
    JLabel demo;
    
    public Intro()
    {
        
        frame.setTitle("Let us start");
        frame.setSize(600,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("welcome.gif")));
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        background = new JLabel();
        frame.add(background);
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        ok = new JButton("OK");
        demo = new JLabel("CSIT 121 Demo System", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(demo);
        ok.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        ok.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
        frame.add(ok);
        
        
        
    }

}
```

What do i need to modify?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another layout. Here is the correct example:

```
public class Intro extends JFrame {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton ok;

    JLabel background;

    JLabel demo;

    public Intro() {

        frame.setTitle("Let us start");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel contentPane = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("welcome.gif"));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        background = new JLabel();
        frame.add(background); // why you need it??? it has no visual effect here
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        ok = new JButton("OK");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(ok);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        demo = new JLabel("CSIT 121 Demo System"); // probably you need to change foreground of label to fit your background image
        frame.add(demo, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Intro::new);
    }
}
```